# Winforms on Linux

Tags: linux, c#, ide

I have an upcoming exam in Database course, which requires me to use WinForms to design a simple application including a login panel, a form for user to enter and retrieve data after that, etc.

The problem is, we have to use Visual Studio (with Windows OS) to have it done in the exam. Yet I'm currently using Linux and prefer neither switching to Windows nor using Virtual Machine (since it requires much RAM and it's always laggy when I open Visual Studio in VM).

I want to know whether there is an equivalent software I can use instead of Visual Studio to create WinForms application and if it does, is it possible to run the application in Windows environment without much effort on installing required packages.

Comment: Will your project only be graded on database, or will it be graded on the Windows  Forms design and .Net code as well?

Comment: Possibly SharpDevelop running on Mono or Wine may work?

Comment: @Chillie The teacher said both, but of course database has more weight on the total grade.

Comment: you might be better off using a VM then. Wine doesn't seem like it currently works well with the latest version of VS and Mono, is technically not the same as .Net. There is also the chance that the project works correctly for you on linux, but fails to build on Windows. I've had that issue between OSX and Win10.